# Using titles instead of slugs for database key lookup?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Would there be much of a performance hit if instead of using a slug to find an article (with the slug being stored in the database), you stored the data as a unique title e.g. `My Article Title` then just took the slug from the URL - `my-article-title`, removed the hyphens / replace with spaces and then do a database search for the specific article?

Comment: You'd probably want to store the slug in the database, as there's no reliable way to translate something like `spot-check-article` to the title `"Spot-Check Article"` (for example, hyphenated words), and it would be a lot slower to have to manipulate the value in the database before comparison. Also, Laravel has a handy `Str::slug()` method that can do this.

Comment: Thanks, add that as an answer and I will select.

Comment: Sure, I can add a quick write-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is valid to search against a `title` column (plain, free-form text), it will be difficult to rely on accuracy when translating a `slug` to `title`, as reversing a `slug` can be problematic. Take the following examples:

```
title                | slug
"Spot-Check Article" | "spot-check-article"
"Bob's Article"      | "bobs-article"
```

If you try to reverse the slug (replace `-` with , and capitalize words), you end up with `Spot Check Article` and `Bobs Article`, and `Model::where('title', 'Spot Check Article')->orWhere('title', 'Bobs Article')->first();` would return no results.

Assuming PHP was responsible for converting the supplied `slug` to a `title`, then searching wouldn't inherently be any slowing than searching directly against a `slug` column, but if you're relying on `mysql` to convert the, then it will be a lot slower. All-in-all, storing the slug in the database, ensuring uniqueness and searching against the `slug` column will be a better approach.